# net::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID, Axios

Tags: reactjs, axios

I am getting errors while accessing https apis even by adding certificate in Axios GET call.

```
let agentOptions = {
  rejectUnauthorized: false,
  ca: "XXXXXXXX"
};
const requestOption = {
    method: "GET",
    httpsAgent: new https.Agent(agentOptions),
    url: "https://someurl.com",
    json: true
  };
axios(requestOption)
      .then((response) => {
        console.log("*****res***", response);
        return response;
      })
      .catch((error) => {
          console.log("**err**", error);
      });
```

Above code is showing below error in browser console:

```
net::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID
```

How Do I resolve this issue? 
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: have you been able to solve this? I get the same net::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID from axios. If I use the URL directly in Chrome, it works.